# Is there an ambiguity in "promoted twice in consecutive years"?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to write the following statement in my resume.

> Promoted twice in consecutive years (2011, 2012) as a top performer in the department.

I want to convey that I got one promotion each in 2011 and 2012, while also subtly bringing to notice that getting promotions in consecutive years is rather rare and special. However, I am worried that this statement could be interpreted to mean that I got 4 promotions. Not sure if "promoted in consecutive years" makes it clear that I got two promotions.

Is the phrase as above okay, or if not, how can I rephrase it to something unambigious? (If the phrase can also be made more "catchy", that's a bonus.)

Comment: You could eliminate the word _twice_: "Promoted in consecutive years (2011, 2012) as a top performer in the department."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that line is ambiguous. As a matter of fact, I initially read it as that you were promoted four times in two years, two times each year. I recommend "Received promotions in 2011 and 2012 as a top performer in the department."